# Brachos on the Pesach Seder

Tags: blessing, passover, passover-seder-hagada

Why don’t we make a Bracha on any of the Mitzvos that we fulfill during the Seder if  we are fulfilling our obligation of remembering the Exodus?

Is each action of the Seder another Mitzvah? If yes, then why would we not make a Bracha on each part of it?

Additionally, why don't we say one general Bracha on the whole Seder upon starting it?

Comment: We do make blessing on Matza and Maror and [arguably (especially for Ashkenazim)] the four cups.

Comment: "Is each action of the Seder another Mitzvah? If yes, then why don't we make a Bracha on each part of the Seder?" Wouldn't the simpler answer, given the fact that you don't know of any such blessings, be 'no'?

Comment: According to some opinions, Hallel in shul is the "bracha".

Comment: @DoubleAA If you can count borei pri hagafen, why not count asher ge'alanu?

Comment: @doni one is before one is after. Not to say you're wrong just one doesn't follow from the other

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the question of why we don't make a general bracha on haggada itself is not a new question . Indeed ,the Rambam in Sefer HaMitzvos 157 counts sippur yeztiyas Miztrayim as one of the mitzvos,and would seemingly require a bracha like any other mitzvas aseh.

The Avudraham page 237(new version) brings this question from the Rif (maybe meant Rabbeinu Peretz) who asks why is there no bracha on the haggadah. He answers that since one fulfills his obligation of sippur yetziyas Mitzrayim in kiddush one does not make a new bracha. This is also the opnion of Rebbeinu Yeruchum and Tzror HaChaim (talmid haRashba). The Rashba answers that since the mitzvah does not have a known measurement it does not require a bracha.
However ,it should be noted that the Meiri(Brachos end of first perek) brings an opinion that indeed one does make a bracha on the haggadah.

There are more answers provided in the Haggadah of Rav Menachem Kasher- Haggada Shelima.

Answer (score 1):

By "The Seder" I think that you mean 
the poem "Kaddesh urchatz."
That poem was made as a memory aid so people would recall all the Mitzvos of the Seder. 
We don't make a bracha on the memory aid.

Kaddesh is a mitzvah and it is accomplished by saying the brachos on wine and kiddush.

Urchatz, washing for the dipping of a vegetable, is a requirement for touching and eating a vegetable. Although the Vilna gaon would make a bracha, most customs are not to. The requirement or mitzvah has nothing to do with Pesach or the Seder. Rather it has to do with how we approach touching wet (dipped) vegetables.

Karpas is a custom to inspire the children to ask about this night.

Yachatz as well.

Maggid is a mitzvah, however, since it has no measure, we don't say a bracha. (Source?)

Rachtzah is normative Jewish practice, a mitzvah d'Rabbanan for which we say a bracha.

Motzi-Motza, eating "Matzah bread", is the start of a meal for which we follow the normative practice of saying the food-bracha of HaMotzi and we add a second mitzva-bracha "Al achilas matza" for the mitzva that goes along with it.

Marror is a special mitzvah of the night for which we say a special mitzva-bracha (but not on the food part).

Korech is a reminder to join the two previous Mitzvos together. Because we are just following the Hillel custom of eating them together, we make no bracha. (Some try not to talk so as to depend on the brachos already made).

Etc.